# How to make auto height content with scroll bar (when overflow) and bottom fixed footer?

Tags: html, css

[model](http://www.myupload.org/files/br8c1x4atxx0tqxx7ero.png)

it's possible? yes|no|javascript?

ok. i'll try.

Here must be:

Header. Fixed size, fixed position (top)

Content. Dynamic height, depends from window, header and footer size. Have sroll if overflow.

Footer. Always bottom fixed position. Fixed size.

Window. No Scroll (!important)

ps. to window. there is a bug or something. if it's Firefox or Opera key 'down' - scroll down. even if "no scroll" - hidden specified.

hope all clear

---

Done.
Tnx.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;} /* do not use universal selector this is just for example */
#header{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;

}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px; /*footer height*/
    top:150px; /* header height */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='header'>
Header content
</div>
<div id="content">
    dynamic content here
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could really make some nicer question.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;} /* do not use universal selector this is just for example */
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome at Stackoverflow,

could you please post a more specific question? Just writing something in the Title and having a real question like "it's possible? yes|no|javascript?" does not help anyone.

To answer your question: yes, it is possible. You just need to use some css.

Comment: there is a link to image that breadboarding what i exactly need. i have some problems with english. so, i've drawned it.